# retrieving data from nested object

Tags: javascript

I have this object example only:

```
{
id: 301
 payload: {
 1: {
  house_no: 1234,
  city: London
  },
 2: {
  house_no: 0000
  city: Paris
  }
 }
}
```

I need to extract only the `house_no and city` for both 1 and 2.
I have tried for loping through like so: *Address passed to the loop is the object above

```
let item = [];
for(let x in address){
      item.push(item[x]);
}

console.log('Address', item.city);
```

This gives me array with undefined elements:

```
[
0: undefined
1: undefined
]
```

Could you guys please help me just retrieving the data i need for each 1,2 : `house_no and city`

Comment: Why are you pushing `item[x]` into your `item` array?

Comment: `item.push(item[x]);`? Of course, you’re going to get `undefined`. Don’t push `item[x]`.

Comment: There are several commas missing in your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.values(address.payload).map(({ house_no, city }) => ({ house_no, city }));
```

This goes over each value in `address.payload` and returns an array of objects with `house_no` and `city`.

```js
const address = {
  id: 301,
  payload: {
   1: {
    house_no: 1234,
    city: 'London'
    },
   2: {
    house_no: 0000,
    city: 'Paris'
    }
  }
};

const result = Object.values(address.payload).map(({ house_no, city }) => ({ house_no, city }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey i really like this solution, reason why i am adding to : let item = []; is  because i want to map over it in the html. I am right to understand that Object.values return array thats why u can then follow it by map...?

Comment: Yeah `Object.values` returns an array so you can then call `.map()` on it which in turn returns an array also. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly access it as below,

```
const {1: obj1, 2: obj2} = address.payload;
```

In here javascript will destructure the payload and assign object 1 into 1 and object 2 into 2. There were some missing commas and quotations in the object which you provided. Therefore I added that also below. Now, obj1 and obj2 will have the 1 and 2 objects where you can extract the data you need out of them easily.

```
let address = {
    id: 301,
     payload: {
     1: {
      house_no: 1234,
      city: "London"
      },
     2: {
      house_no: 0000,
      city: "Paris"
      }
     }
    };

const {1: obj1, 2: obj2} = address.payload;
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj1.city);
console.log(obj1.house_no);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access object properties directly without looping:

```
<script>
  var obj = {
    id: 301,
    payload: {
    1: {
      house_no: 1234,
      city: "London"
      },
    2: {
      house_no: 0000,
      city: "Paris"
      }
    }
  }
  var address1 = obj.payload[1].house_no + " " + obj.payload[1].city;
  var address2 = obj.payload[2].house_no + " " + obj.payload[2].city;
</script>
```